# Print the percentages of each element in the column

Tags: r, dataframe, count

My data frame:

```
structure(list(GROUP = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
    col1 = c("S", "S", "S", "S", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), col2 = c("a", 
    "a", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

My code:

```
    comb <- list(c(2, 3))
    
    quantity.elem <- function(dat) { 
      do.call(rbind, lapply(comb, function(x) {
        col1 <- dat[[x[1]]]
        col2 <- dat[[x[2]]]
        data.frame(NAME = sprintf('Group %s by Group %s', x[1], x[2]),
                    
                   p <- table(dat[[x[1]]]),
                                   p.2 <- table(dat[[x[2]]]),
                                   p.matrix <- round((prop.table(proc, 1) * 100), 1),
                                   p.matrix.2 <- round((prop.table(proc.2, 1) * 100), 1), 
col <- paste0(paste0(names(p),": ",as.numeric(p)," ","(",as.numeric(p.matrix),"%",")"),"-",paste0(names(p.2),": ",as.numeric(p.2)," ","(",as.numeric(p.matrix.2),"%",")"),collapse = "\n")
 
                   )
        
       
      }))
    }
    
    result <- purrr::map_df(split(data, data$GROUP), quantity.elem, .id = 'Group')
```

In the last column, I was able to output the number of each column element. But I still need to output how many percent of the total number is an element

What the program outputs:

```
|GROUP|                   quan                 |
|-----|----------------------------------------|
|  1  |F:3(100%)-a:1(100%) S: 2(100%)-s:4(100%)|
|  2  |F:2(100%)-a:1(100%) S: 2(100%)-s:3(100%)|
```

what I want to get:

```
|GROUP|                   quan                 |
|-----|----------------------------------------|
|  1  |F:3(60%)-a:1(20%) S: 2(40%)-s:4(80%)   |
|  2  |F:2(50%)-a:1(25%) S: 2(50%)-s:3(75%)    |
```

The number of elements outputs correctly, and the percentages are always 100% for some reason and do not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly redid the output and it worked

```
prop.matrix <- round((prop.table(proc) * 100), 1)
 prop.matrix.2 <- round((prop.table(proc.2) * 100), 1)
```